# Enable horizontal scrolling in Ubuntu

Tags: gnome, touchpad

There is no option in Mouse & Touchpad Settings to enable horizontal scrolling in Ubuntu 13.04+ (Raring/Saucy/Trusty) (GNOME 3.8+):

[image: Mouse & Touchpad Settings]

No horizontal scrolling even by enabling *two finger scroll* or *content sticks to fingers*.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There’s a way through **dconf Editor**; so:

1. open dconf Editor through the Dash;
2. go to **org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad**;
3. check **horiz-scroll-enabled**, as you see in the screenshot.

[image: Enable horizontal scrolling]

**Edit:**
Dconf Editor was pre-installed on 13.04, where I first faced the problem; but on 13.10 and 14.04 it’s easier to use **gsettings**, see [Samuel Cavazos’s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/332803/89497).

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand the reason for removing that option from the control panel :/

Comment: Yeah, me too. Seems it’s about GNOME project, where functionality is sacrificed for simplicity!

Comment: At least they don't make it impossible ;)

Comment: This is a moment when I wish stackoverflow framework permitted multiple upvotes ;) thanks

Comment: @AliNa I aproved an edit that compliments your findings.

Comment: excellent answer to also disable horizontal scrolling, or sideways scrolling (pushing some keywords here).

Comment: What if there is no touchpad key? FYI: My laptop gots touchpad. v16.04

Comment: In 16.04, i think they place the touchpad setting in other place, try use dconf Editor, browse to org - gnome - desktop - peripherals - touchpad, all the touchpad setting is here.

Answer (score 30):

Alternative way: run this in your command line

```
synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1
```

Comment: Does it enable edge scrolling too if I’ve disabled two-finger scrolling?

Comment: I think edge scrolling is controlled by other options: `VertEdgeScroll` and `HorizEdgeScroll`

Comment: Neither dconf editor nor gsettings worked for me on Lubuntu 14.04, but this one did: `synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1`

Comment: @iynque Works on Xubuntu 16.04 as well. How do you make this permanent?

Comment: I am on Lubuntu 17.04 and i got an error message stating: `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`.

Comment: Anyone know how to make this persistent between boots? I added the command to startup applications, but I feel like this is a bad way to do it

Comment: This enabled it for touch pad only, not the mouse scroll button, in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Works like a charm in DeepIN 15.9

Comment: @Calixte Add it to Startup Applications (in the menu), or to `/etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 22):

Or just run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true"
```

in a terminal

Comment: This trick also works great if you have the opposite goal: turning the horizontal scroll off. Just set the variable to “false” instead of “true”.

Comment: It said to set the value of the key. Nothing happened.

Comment: Ran gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true" in Terminal, nothing happened.

Comment: `$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad horiz-scroll-enabled "true"` 
> `No such schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad'`

Comment: The command probably doesn't work anymore. Ubuntu has change over the years since I posted this and I've switched over to another distro.

Comment: I am on Lubuntu 17.04 and also got the `No such schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad'` message.

Answer (score 9):

Configure your Linux key binding to make Shift+Mouse wheel send an horizontal scroll event:

- Install xbindkeys xautomation
- Edit ~/.xbindkeysrc.scm and write:

  ```
    ; bind shift + vertical scroll to horizontal scroll events
    (xbindkey '(shift "b:4") "xte 'mouseclick 6'")
    (xbindkey '(shift "b:5") "xte 'mouseclick 7'")
  ```

Run `xbindkeys`.

Also, for Firefox 17+, open `about:config` and set:

- `general.autoScroll = true`
- `mousewheel.with_shift.action = 1`
- `mousewheel.with_shift.action.override_x=1` if on Firefox >= 121 (see the comment)
- Optionally, configure scroll speed: `mousewheel.with_shift.delta_multiplier_x = 300`

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/xnez3g/horizontal-scroll-with-mouse-under-linux

I got both working. Although for `xbindkeys`, some apps stick with their own behavior, for instance Firefox.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you sooo much, you're the best.

Comment: works for me on ubuntu 23.04

Comment: stopped working after upgrade to 23.10 :-(

Comment: the problem with 23.10 is only with firefox and can be fixed by setting
```mousewheel.with_shift.action = 4```
source of knowledge: https://support.mozilla.org/zu/questions/1358257

Comment: after upgrade of Firefox to 121 (wayland is default instead of X), I needed to set also `mousewheel.with_shift.action.override_x=1` and then scrolling started to work again

Answer (score 4):

On the MATE desktop variant, I found the following dconf path to work:

/org/mate/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/horizontal-two-finger-scrolling

If you do not already have the dconf-editor, you will want to run `sudo apt install dconf-editor`

Start dconf-editor and then search for "horizontal-two" and that should be specific enough to find it:

[image: Screenshot of changing /org/mate/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/horizontal-two-finger-scrolling setting]

I'm using a laptop with a Synaptics touchpad running Ubuntu (MATE) 18.04.

Yonn Trimoreau says that on Cinnamon, the following dconf path should work:

/org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/peripherals/touchpad/horizontal-scrolling

You would install the same dconf-editor, but search for "horizontal-scrolling" and then set it to on.

Comment: sudo apt install dconf-editor

Comment: On Cinnamon: org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad.horizontal-scrolling

Comment: @YonnTrimoreau took the liberty of editing my answer to include your note. Feel free to edit my answer if you see anything that needs changing or could be improved.

Comment: Working great on Cinnamon 20.1, upon closing `dconf-editor` Firefox immediately started scrolling horizontally. Baffles me why the default isn't True.