# Microsoft Explorer Touch Mouse compatibility

Tags: mouse, compatibility, mouse-scroll, scrolling

Is the Microsoft Explorer Touch Mouse fully compliant with Ubuntu? In particular the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: I go with "Yes", there is no reason why it should not. But you may have to enable horizontal scrolling in ubuntu:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/264091/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu-13-04-and-13-10

Answer (score 0):

I'm using one so I can confirm without any doubt that it works.

Note that there are no proprietary drivers for the mouse, so the special buttons (top of scroll and bottom of scroll) cannot as of now be mapped.

Comment: Is this a "smooth", "pixel-perfect", "stepless" scrolling in Evince or Gedit or gnome-terminal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the Microsoft Explorer Touch mouse is compatible! Horizontal and vertical scroll also. It also comes with PageUp/PageDown buttons on the scroll.