# How to enable horizontal mouse wheel scrolling in unity?

Tags: 12.04, mouse-wheel

I've read a few related questions:

[Enable horizontal scrolling in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264091/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2097030

But hasn't given me the answer. Just plugged in a mouse in 12.04 and there's no horizontal scrolling with the mousewheel. Instead it has strange behaviour where text is changed if mousewheel is held down and moved over it. HP mouse, feature works on windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

If you are under Ubuntu, you have to install two packages: xbindkeys and xautomation.

To enable the horizontal scroll with key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+MouseWheel, run these commands on Terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xautomation
$ echo "; bind shift + vertical scroll to horizontal scroll events
>  (xbindkey '(shift \"b:4\") \"xte 'mouseclick 6'\")
>  (xbindkey '(shift \"b:5\") \"xte 'mouseclick 7'\")" >> .xbindkeysrc.scm

$ xbindkeys
```