# Swap vertical and horizontal scroll axis

Tags: scrolling

Is there a way to swap the vertical and horizontal scroll axes, e.g., so that when scrolling right on the touchpad it scrolls down on screen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable horizontal scrolling in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/264091/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Rahul no, that's not right. The OP wants to swap vertical and horizontal scrolling, not enable horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

Get your mouse name with:

```
xinput
```

Get your button mapping with:

```
xinput get-button-map "Mouse Name"
```

This will give something like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Change the scroll axis mapping like this:

```
xinput set-button-map 'Mouse Name' 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 8 9
```

Notice how 4 and 5 buttons are exchanged with 6 and 7. They usually correspond to the scrolling axis buttons. You can use `xev` to check before and after.

Some applications, like chromium may need to be restarted to be aware of this changes.

Answer (score -1):

For swapping vertical scroll axis you just have to enable the natural scrolling. You can find it under settings -> devices -> mouse and touchpad. In 17.04 this option inverted the horizontal scroll axis too, but if you have the 18.04 it does not seems to work at the moment.