# Swap vert & horiz scrolling: remapping buttons has no effect

Tags: mouse, xinput, remapping, mouse-wheel

My mouse has a vertical and horizontal scroll wheel. I would like to swap them so that the original vertical wheel controls horizontal scrolling and vice versa.

So far:

1. I have used `xev` to identify the button numbers: 4 (scroll up), 5 (scroll down), 6 (scroll left), 7 (scroll right).
2. Used `xinput --set-button-map` to remap the buttons as I want them
3. Checked the procedure with `xev` and `xinput --get-button-map`. They both show the new mapping. This is xinput's output:  `1 2 3 6 7 5 4 8 2 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20`
4. Restarted open applications, as suggested in [Ask Ubuntu: Swap vertical and horizontal scroll axis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867029/swap-vertical-and-horizontal-scroll-axis)
5. Aside: I have remapped button 9 to be button 2 and this is working as expected.

Despite `xev` showing the buttons being mapped as I want them the vertical and horizontal scrolling behaviour has not changed in any of my applications, for example in Chrome and Inkscape. I am using KDE, in case that is relevant.

What am I missing?