# Re-enable horizontal scrolling in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: touchpad, dell, 17.10, xps, scrolling

Horizontal scrolling on my touchpad was disabled upon upgrading to 17.10 and I can't find a way to re-enable it in the settings.

Two finger (horizontal and vertical) scrolling was the default behavior when I was using 16.10, even after I had switched to the GNOME desktop. However, there seems to be no settings for this both in the settings menu and dconf that I can find.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and couldn't find the option in `dconf-editor` (/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/ doesn't help). I found this command [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264091/enable-horizontal-scrolling-in-ubuntu) and now horizontal scrolling seems to be working just fine. Give it a try.

`synclient HorizTwoFingerScroll=1`

And make your fix persistent using this tip by monkbroc:

[How do I make my synclient settings stick?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290009/how-do-i-make-my-synclient-settings-stick)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gnome right now,

go to settings then mouse and touchpad, in the touchpad tab set your settings like shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I don't see the relevant option. (Image for referrence: https://imgur.com/a/yQeJ3 )

What settings app are you using?